# Query to fetch distinct rows with below requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample date in the table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+---+
| School |  Class  | Student | Student desc | Section   |    Date    |   |
+--------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+---+
| ABC    | Grade 2 | Stud 1  | AAA          | Mango     | 5/12/2015  | 1 |
| DEF    | Grade 2 | Stud 1  | AAA          | Mango     | 12/25/2018 |   |
| DEF    | Grade 2 | Stud 1  | AAA          | Orange    | 9/8/2016   |   |
| GHI    | Grade 3 | Stud 2  | BBB          | Apple     | 12/28/2016 | 2 |
| JKL    | Grade 3 | Stud 2  | BBB          | Pear      | 12/19/2016 |   |
| ABC    | Grade 2 | Stud 3  | CCC          | Guava     | 12/28/2016 | 3 |
| GHI    | Grade 3 | Stud 4  | DDD          | StarFruit | 9/8/2018   | 4 |
+--------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+---+
```

Ideally mapping should be 1 student is only get assigned to one section in a class.

I need to build the query to fetch the data to meet below requirement:-

> 1. Irrespective of the School need to show the distinct data for those students which get assigned to multiple sections within same class.

```
+--------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
| School |  Class  | Student | Student desc | Section  |    Date    |
+--------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
| DEF    | Grade 2 | Stud 1  | AAA          | Mango    | 12/25/2018 |
| DEF    | Grade 2 | Stud 1  | AAA          | Orange   | 9/8/2016   |
| GHI    | Grade 3 | Stud 2  | BBB          | Apple    | 12/28/2016 |
| JKL    | Grade 3 | Stud 2  | BBB          | Pear     | 12/19/2016 |
+--------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

Below is the query that provides the correct data *if school information is fetched*:

```
select  distinct a.class
                    ,a.student
                    ,a.Stud desc
                    ,a.section
                    ,to_date(max(a.date),'MM-DD-YYYY')"Date"
      from         Table1 a,
    (   select  class
               ,student
               ,count(distinct section) cot       
          from Table1 c 
         where 1=1
           and class is not null
           and incoming_qty >= 1
      group by class
              ,student
        Having count(distinct section) > 1   
      ) b
     where   1=1
     and     a.class = b.class
     and     a.student=b.student
     and     b.cot > 1
     and     b.class is not null
     and     a.incoming_qty_new >= 1
     group by a.class,a.student,a.Stud desc,a.section
     order by  a.class,a.student,a.Stud desc,a.section;
```

But query not working as per expectation while trying to fetch the school detail.

Please suggest.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of analytic functions usage for your data. Try to extend it for your specific case.

```
WITH t(School, Class, Student, StudentDesc, SectionName, Dates) AS
  (
    SELECT 'ABC','Grade 2','Stud 1','AAA','Mango',date'2015-05-12' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DEF','Grade 2','Stud 1','AAA','Mango',date'2018-12-25' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DEF','Grade 2','Stud 1','AAA','Orange',date'2016-09-08' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GHI','Grade 3','Stud 2','BBB','Apple',date'2016-12-28' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JKL','Grade 3','Stud 2','BBB','Pear',date'2016-12-19' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC','Grade 2','Stud 3','CCC','Guava',date'2016-12-28' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GHI','Grade 3','Stud 4','DDD','StarFruit',date'2018-09-08' FROM dual
  )

SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(DISTINCT SectionName) OVER (PARTITION BY Class, Student) AS cntStudentSections,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Class, Student ORDER BY Dates) AS StudentRowNumber
      FROM t 
     ) 
WHERE cntStudentSections > 1 AND StudentRowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Add `section` in `partition by` for `row_number` like in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a70816b2d6358df07f18e1afbcab0a2a). Your query returns only two rows, when you make this correction output will be like OP wanted.

Comment: @PonderStibbons, I'm trying to provide direction here and hope OP can try to modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by class, student, section) as cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Showing duplicate row for Location :

Comment: Same issue with the above mentioned query.

Comment: @magickk . . . There is nothing called `location` in the question, so I have no idea what you are referring to.  I do notice that the question involves `section` and I had missed that in the answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad,  Its School column which i am referring. When School field get added in the select clause the data is not coming as per expectation.

Comment: @magickk . . . If you want duplicates without taking school into account, then remove `school` from the `partition by` (as I just did).